# How to add color to Unicode character inside dropdown select

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, unicode, drop-down-menu, playing-cards

I have a select box with each suit of the playing cards as an option. I also gave each option a Unicode character. Now I want to add color to the Unicode characters. For example, Hearts would be red. But I can't figure out how to do this.

I know adding `<span>` inside `<option>` is a bad idea so I can't style each char as a separate span element.

So how do I accomplish this?

```
<select class = "form-control">
    <option value = "clubs">&clubs; Clubs</option>
    <option value = "diamonds">&diams; Diamonds</option>
    <option value = "hearts">&hearts; Hearts</option>
    <option value = "spades">&spades; Spades</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are somewhat limited because the HTML spec says to treat the contents of an option tag as just text.  For Chrome and Firefox you can exploit a little trick where if the select tag has a size property, you can use the ::first-letter property to style the option:

CSS:

```
option.red::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select size="4" class = "form-control">
    <option value = "clubs">&clubs; Clubs</option>
    <option class="red" value = "diamonds">&diams; Diamonds</option>
    <option class="red" value = "hearts">&hearts; Hearts</option>
    <option value = "spades">&spades; Spades</option>
</select>
```

See this in action at https://jsfiddle.net/cno3tog7/  For a more cross-browser approach, I'd suggest using something that builds a non-native select, such as using Bootstrap.

Comment: Can you give an example of a non-native select?

Comment: It depends on what you want to use (jQuery, Bootstrap, etc.)  There's an interesting plugin for bootstrap at https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/ that lets you do the HTML as a normal select element and then it overrides the display. Look down that page for the example "Style Individual Options" for how they let you style the options. You could use that approach and use the ::first-letter selector on it.

Comment: I have used the above selectpicker, styling it can be tricky because it turns a normal select box into a button on the browser. I will look for a JQuery UI solution